# Make sure some object is loaded from server before $locationChangeStart event handler gets executed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I have a handler bound to `$location`'s `$locationChangeStart` event. Within that even handler, some user object coming from the server is required. Below is the code (simplified) that I have:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('userSrv', function($http) {
  var currentUser = null;
  var service = {
    loadUser: function() {
      $http.get('/api/load_user', function(user) {
        currentUser = user;
      });
    },
    isLoggedIn: function() {
      return !!currentUser;
    }
  };
  return service;
})
.run(function($rootScope, userSrv) {
  userSrv.loadUser();  // load user info

  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(ev, next, current) {
    // alway false because the $http call in loadUser() has not being resolved at this point.
    if (userSrv.isLoggedIn()) { 
      console.log('User is logged in. Please proceed');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Login first');
    }
  });
});
```

The problem with the above code is that the `$locationChangeStart` event handler gets executed before the `userSrv` finishes loading user object from the server. As a result, `userSrv.isLoggedIn()` would return `false` even when it really should have been `true`.

Note that the user object needs loaded only once because it gets cached throughout the browsing session. What can I do to make sure the user object is loaded completed before the `$locationChangeStart` event handler gets executed?

Comment: Don't wait for that event, broadcast a different event in the callback after setting currentUser.

Comment: @ZackArgyle - I need to use that event in order to intervene the location change process.